# Show div when leaving page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to show a DIV when leaving a page? I have a form that needs to be shown when the user leaves the page.

I can make it so the popup appears upon loading of the page but not when leaving.

Thanks,
Mani

www.jsfiddle.net/Sjk9E/4

Comment: please fiddle your code to elaborate more on this.

Comment: Use the `window.onunload` event.

Comment: okay! where is the  code stuff you've tried?

Comment: As far i can tell, there is no cross browser solution to do that

Comment: But the user will never see the div since the page is unloading and it is milliseconds of time!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sjk9E/4/ - for some reason in the fiddle the X close button isn't working

Answer (score 1):

> If I get you correctly, you want to know when a tab/window is effectively closed. Well, afaik your only way in Javascript to detect that kind of stuff are **onunload** & **onbeforeunload** events.
>
> Unfortunately (or fortunately?), those events are also fired when you
>   leave a site over a link or your browsers back button. So this is the
>   best answer I can give, I don't think you can natively detect a pure
>   close in Javascript. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

[javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

3 seconds of google. Just saying.

Comment: Please mark as duplicate and leave a comment instead of copying a whole answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use `window.onbeforeunload` javascript event.